# How to do Typesafe JSON with fields of Enum type?

Tags: json, typescript, enums

I have some JSON files that conform to TypeScript interfaces that I have defined.

For the most part, when importing such JSON files and assigning them to typed variables, TypeScript is able to infer the type signature automatically (see `behaves exactly as I want` in the code below). However when the type includes **string enums**, it no longer works (see `DOES NOT behave`).

The following is a working [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

**valid.json**

```
{ "id": 3.14159 }
```

**invalid.json**

```
{ "id": "3.14159" }
```

**validEnum.json**

```
{ "color": "red" }
```

**invalidEnum.json**

```
{ "color": "chartreuse" }
```

**index.ts**

```
import validJson from './valid.json'
import invalidJson from './invalid.json'
import validJsonEnum from './validEnum.json'
import invalidJsonEnum from './invalidEnum.json'

type ColorType = 'red' | 'blue' | 'yellow'

type IJsonType = {"id": number}
type IJsonTypeWithEnum = {"color": ColorType}

// behaves exactly as I want
const a: IJsonType = validJson    // no error
const b: IJsonType = invalidJson  // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

// DOES NOT behave as I want: SHOULD NOT error
const c: IJsonTypeWithEnum = validJsonEnum    // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ColorType'.

// DOES NOT behave as I want: error should be that "chartreuse" is not assignable to type 'ColorType'
const d: IJsonTypeWithEnum = invalidJsonEnum  // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ColorType'.
```

I can make the error go away with `type IJsonTypeWithEnum = {"color": string}`, but that defeats the purpose.

Is there any work-around or a compiler switch to make TypeScript recognize enum values inside JSON as strings? Or is it a dead-end TypeScript limitation for JSON type inference?

Comment: If you don't find a better alternative - have a look at `io-ts`.

Comment: This question can be made far easier to understand as well as work on if you follow SO guildines for [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'll submit an edit suggestion shortly.

Comment: So the MRE in my submitted edit reproduces your error message, but I can't get the positive case to work ("TypeScript is able to infer the type signature automatically"). Can you accept my edit and then add code showing how it *does* work when enum strings are not involved? Now you can see the importance of an MRE for this question. I'll upvote the question once it gets a solid MRE.

Comment: @Inigo I've check your edit. Thanks for the effect but it's not correct. Importing a `.json` file in recent version of TS is allowed and it will be converted to a well-typed object. Your MRE's string template should be replaced by object literal to reflect the fact. FYI I improve your edit and apply it.

Comment: @hackape i'm not sure it makes a difference as i think the MRE represents either way (the error message is identical), but yes probably safer to hew closest to the OP's stated method. thx.   We still need the positive case the OP claims (see above comment). I can't repro it, so this entire thing remains suspect.

Comment: @Inigo the error message is only superficially identical, but for totally different reason. You comment to the other answer `Conversion of type 'string' to type 'IJsonType' may be a mistake` that’s because originally you declare `jsonData` as a string using string template, which is not the case if you import it from a `.json` file.

Comment: @vitaly-t it would have been nice if you posted an MRE in the first place. Collectively a lot of time has been spent on doing this for you. You should award me the bounty just for that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `as const`, but if you import json - then I'm not sure it's possible.

Also `amakhrov` pointed to the current TS issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063

Until the issue has been fixed / implemented you can write a type assertion function to validate the type, check `verifyColor` below. It takes an argument and asserts it's `IJsonTypeWithEnum`.

```js
// helps to detect flexible objects
export const isObject = (value: unknown): value is {[key in keyof any]: unknown} => { 
    return typeof value === 'object' && value !== null;
}

// solves issues with for key of
export const objectKeys = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(value: T): Array<K> => {
    return <Array<K>>Object.keys(value);
};

// THAT'S THE ANSWER
// verifies colors
const verifyColor = (value: unknown): value is IJsonTypeWithEnum => {
    if (!isObject(value)) { 
        return false;
    }
    for (const key of objectKeys(ColorType)) {
        if (ColorType[key] === value.color) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};


const validJson: unknown = { "id": 3.14159 };
const invalidJson: unknown = { "id": "3.14159" };
const validJsonEnum: unknown = { "color": "red" };
const invalidJsonEnum: unknown = { "color": "chartreuse" };

enum ColorType {
    red = 'red',
    blue = 'blue',
    yellow = 'yellow',
}

type IJsonType = {"id": number}
type IJsonTypeWithEnum = { "color": ColorType }

// asserting type
if (verifyColor(validJsonEnum)) { // add || 1 to check failure
    const c: IJsonTypeWithEnum = validJsonEnum; // no error anymore
}

// asserting type
if (verifyColor(invalidJsonEnum)) { // add || 1 to check failure
    const d: IJsonTypeWithEnum = invalidJsonEnum  // no error anymore
}
```

Comment: There is already an answer by Damien Plewa, with pretty much the same. Plus answer from amakharov, with the right issue link. A good answer should include both things ;)

Comment: I don’t see answers with type assertions that solves the issue without postponing code delivery and waiting for a new ts version

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for JSON files though. The question is about auto-inferring data from JSON files, not from inline JSON data.

Comment: Damien Plewa uses cast of type. It’s not typesafe and forces type. When in my answer there is a typesafe check that guarantees correct values.

Comment: Right. With type assertion you can use json files and be sure that color has right value.

Comment: all the thing is `value is { color: ColorType }`, you can take any value - check it fits type you want to use in a block.

Comment: I've updated the code example to show how it works when all json data is unknown (unknown types).

Comment: Thank you! Could you, please add that which `amakhrov` suggested, i.e. the link to ongoing feature development, for completeness of the answer? Cheers!

Comment: Updated, also I removed the `cast` thing because anyway it's not a solution, and added more info about the type assertion function.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use type assertion

```
const data: IJsonType = jsonData as IJsonType;
```

Comment: this yields the error `Conversion of type 'string' to type 'IJsonType' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.(2352)`

Comment: Doesn't this go against automatic type inference? The idea is to make TypeScript produce compile-time error when there is mismatch between the type and data inside JSON.

Comment: @vitaly-t Both answers provide useful info. I understand wht you want to archive but currently TS isn’t capable to do that, and I suspect it ever will.

Comment: You see a string literal value `"foo"` can be inferred as `string` type or `'foo'` type. They’re both valid, but you must choose one. TS choose `string` by default cus that’s the common case. If you wanna the other option, you must use the `as const` suffix to tell TS engine your intention. This is doable in a `.ts` file like the other answer suggest. However, in a `.json` file it’ll be invalid syntax. I’m not sure if a TS plugin can provide such enhanced feature. So it seems to me, type assertion is the only way out for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript will not cast it for you in this case. You will need to typecast it yourself

```js
type ColorType = 'red' | 'blue' | 'yellow';

type IJsonType = {"color" : ColorType}


let validJson = {
   "color": "red" as ColorType
  // or
  // "color": "red" as const
}


let invalidJson = {
   "color": "chartreuse"
}


const data1: IJsonType = validJson;  // this MUST NOT error

const data2: IJsonType = invalidJson;
```

[image: data1 now valid]

Comment: Does not actually solve the problem: the JSON are `.json` files and you can't put type annotations in a JSON file.  Fault lies with the lack of a correct MRE. I've submitted an edit that includes one, awaiting approval.

Comment: @Inigo, Json is a file and the data is suppose to be a run-time thing. What you are trying check is a run-time error at compile time?

Comment: It's not my question but if you look at the the original post, yes, that is what he wants. It's not unreasonable, since Typescript *can* statically catch `string` vs `number` mismatches when assigning the JSON derived object to `IJsonType`.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for auto-type inference from JSON files, not from in-code JSON.

Answer (score 2):

It's currently impossible in Typescript.
There is an open issue/proposal for that: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063 (and a few similar ones).

Comment: Thank you, this is a very useful link indeed. But other than that, a temporary `const` work-around can be used in the meantime, as suggested by others. A good answer should include both things, IMO. Therefore, I'm having trouble which answer to accept :)